# Automate the boring stuff with python chapter_8 MadLibs

Tags: python

Hello this exercise says: 
Create a Mad Libs program that reads in text files and lets the user add their own text anywhere the word ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, or VERB appears in the text file.

textfile = The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was 
unnafected by these events.

What I have so far is :

```
import re
#filename = input('Input the Filename: ')

with open('madlibs.txt') as file:
    content = file.read()
file.close()

regex = re.compile(r'ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB|ADVERB')
#regex = re.compile('[A-Z]{3,}')
matches = regex.findall(content)
#newWord = []

for word in matches:
    user_input = input('Enter %s: ' % word)
  # newWord.append(user_input)
    new_content = content.replace(word,user_input,1)
print(new_content)
```

My input is:

```
Enter ADJECTIVE: heavy
Enter NOUN: whale
Enter VERB: runs
Enter NOUN: door
```

And my output:

```
The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the door and then VERB. A nearby door was
unnafected by these events.
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? It seems that I can't change ADJECTIVE and VERB for some reason, i also tried the commented regex with uppercase and it does the same so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I had to also replace content.replace(word,user_input), with content.replace(word,user_input,1) so that it replaces noun's correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `content`, but because you aren't, it's overwriting your changes until the very last word:

```py
for word in matches:
    user_input = input('Enter %s: ' % word)
    content = content.replace(word,user_input)  # overwrite content here

print(content)
```

Or, if you prefer to keep `content` the same:

```py
new_content = content 

for word in matches:
    user_input = input('Enter %s: ' % word)
    new_content = new_content.replace(word,user_input)  # overwrite new_content here

print(new_content)
```

Strings in python are immutable, meaning that they will not be changed in-place, and instead must be re-assigned:

```py
somestring = "this is a string"

for word in ["is", "a"]:
    newstring = somestring.replace(word, "aaaa")

print(newstring)
# this is aaaa string

print(somestring)
# this is a string
```

Note that `somestring` is still the original value. The first `replace` *did* happen, it just was overwritten when the result of `somestring.replace("a", "aaaa")` was reassigned.

Broken into steps:

```py
somestring = "this is a string"

newstring = somestring.replace("is", "aaaa")
# this aaaa a string

newstring = somestring.replace("a", "aaaa")
# this is aaaa string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# mad_libs.py - Playing mad libs game
# Usage: python3 mad_libs.py save - Save a mad lib phrase from clip board
#        python3 mad_libs.py - Play the mad libs game.
# Caution: Must save at least one phrase before playing.

import shelve, pyclip, random, sys, re
import pyinputplus as pyi

# Open shelve file
shelfFile = shelve.open('mad_libs')

# Add phrase to the database by pasting from clipboard
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'save':
    shelfFile[str(len(shelfFile))] = pyclip.paste().decode()
    print("Phrase saved.")
    sys.exit()

# Get a random phrase from database and display
phrase = shelfFile[str(random.randrange(len(shelfFile)))]

# Regex for finding match
matLibsRegex = re.compile(r'(ADJECTIVE)|(NOUN)|(VERB)|(ADVERB)')

print(phrase)
while True:
    # Find all the matches and replace with user's input
    match = matLibsRegex.search(phrase)

    if match == None:  # Return None if there is no match
        break

    prompt = f"Enter an {match.group().lower()}: " if match.group(
    )[0] in 'Aa' else f"Enter a {match.group().lower()}: "

    substitute = pyi.inputStr(prompt)
    phrase = phrase.replace(match.group(), substitute, 1)  # Replace the fill-in space with user's input

# Print the final phrase and save it to file
print(phrase)

result = open('mad_libs_result.txt', 'a')
result.write(phrase + '\n')
result.close()
shelfFile.close()
```

#### I hope this could enhance your code.

Since this post is about mad libs and I would like to drop my solutions here for upcoming learners. I combine the functionality of Mad Libs exercise and Extend Multi-Clipbaord exercise.